# Performance issues using DialContext in Go

Tags: http, go

I did a quick benchmark using Go's built-in `http.Client` and `net`. It resulted in some noticeable performance issues when using `DialContext` as opposed to when not using it.

I am basically trying to imitate a use case we have in my company where that `http.Client` setup is way less performant than the default configuration when used exactly for the same things. And I noticed commenting the `DialContext` part made it go faster.

The benchmark just opens a pool of threads (8 in the example) to create connections to a simple URL, using a buffered channel of the same size as number of threads (8).

Here is the code with `DialContext` (2.266333805s):

```
func main() {
    var httpClient *http.Client

    httpClient = &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
                Timeout:   3 * time.Second,
                KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
                DualStack: true,
            }).DialContext,
        },
    }

    url := "https://stackoverflow.com/"
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    threads := 8
    wg.Add(threads)
    c := make(chan struct{}, threads)

    start := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < threads; i++ {
        go func() {
            for range c {
                req, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)
                resp, err := httpClient.Do(req)
                if err == nil {
                    resp.Body.Close()
                }
            }
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }

    for i := 0; i < 200; i++ {
        c <- struct{}{}
    }
    close(c)
    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println(time.Since(start))
}
```

**The outputed time was 2.266333805s**

And here is the code without `DialContext` (731.154103ms):

```
func main() {
    var httpClient *http.Client

    httpClient = &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
        },
    }

    url := "https://stackoverflow.com/"
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    threads := 8
    wg.Add(threads)
    c := make(chan struct{}, threads)

    start := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < threads; i++ {
        go func() {
            for range c {
                req, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)
                resp, err := httpClient.Do(req)
                if err == nil {
                    resp.Body.Close()
                }
            }
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }

    for i := 0; i < 200; i++ {
        c <- struct{}{}
    }
    close(c)
    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println(time.Since(start))
}
```

**The outputed time was 731.154103ms**

The difference between results was consistent among several runs of the program.

Does anyone has a clue about why this is happening?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** So I tried `net/http/httptrace` and I made sure the body of the response was fully read and closed:

```
go func() {
    for range c {
        req, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)
        req = req.WithContext(httptrace.WithClientTrace(req.Context(), &httptrace.ClientTrace{
            GotConn: t.gotConn,
        }))
        resp, _ := httpClient.Do(req)
        ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        resp.Body.Close()
    }
    wg.Done()
}()
```

The findings where interesting when using `DialContext` vs not using it.

**NOT USING DialContext:**

```
time taken to run 200 requests: 5.639808793s
new connections: 1
reused connections: 199
```

**USING DialContext:**

```
time taken to run 200 requests: 5.682882723s
new connections: 8
reused connections: 192
```

It is faster... But why one opens 8 new connections, and the other one just 1?

Comment: 1) execute your benchmarks using the [benchmarking facility](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks); 2) you're tuning several settings in your `DialContext` that you're leaving at default in the other example

Comment: You also are not checking the responses at all. Chances are after the first run your connections are being rejected for abuse.

Comment: Same thing happened when using just `DialContext: http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).DialContext` :(

Comment: I am basically trying to imitate a use case we have in my company where that `http.Client` setup is way less performant than the default configuration when used exactly for the same things. And I noticed commenting the `DialContext` part made it go faster.

Comment: @JimB I tried several times in different orders, and the one with `DialContext` was always slower.

Comment: Hey, @RebecaMachado! Do read this: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18601 I think you're right. Dial and friends seem to be slow; will investigate further.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you would be getting such large differences is if one transport is reusing the connections, and the other is not. In order to ensure you can reuse the connection, you must *always* read the response body. It is possible that in some cases the connection would be reused without explicitly reading the body, but it's never guaranteed and depends on many things like the remote server closing the connection, whether the response was fully buffered by the `Transport`, and if there was a context on the request.

The [`net/http/httptrace`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptrace/) package can give you insight into a lot of the request internals, including whether the connections were reused or not. See https://blog.golang.org/http-tracing for examples.

Setting `DisableKeepAlive` will always prevent the connections from being reused, making both similarly slow. Always reading the response like so will make both similarly fast:

```
req, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)
resp, err := httpClient.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
    continue
}
io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, resp.Body)
resp.Body.Close()
```

If you want a cap on how much can be read before dropping the connection, you can simply wrap the body in an [`io.LimitedReader`](https://pkg.go.dev/io/?tab=doc#LimitedReader)

Comment: Thank you so much. Your suggestion of using `net/http/httptrace` showed you were right about reusing connections. I also did some further reading to be sure the response body was always being Read. However, I added an EDIT section on the post to show my results. Mind taking a look at them?

Comment: There is obviously some difference in the serialization of the initial request calls, but in the end it doesn't really matter. You would have to look deeper into the internals to see why, but you are somewhat limited in concurrent request speed by the single transport and client anyway.